# How do I access the underlying SQLite database when using storm-gen for Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, storm-gen

I'm using the [storm-gen](https://github.com/turbomanage/storm-gen) ORM for Android SQLite and want to run a raw SQL query. How can I get access to the underlying SQLiteDatabase class?

Comment: I answered this hoping to create a tag for storm-gen but don't have sufficient reputation to do so. Please retag it #storm-gen if you're able so as not to clutter the #android-sqlite stream.

Comment: Good news! storm-gen was just pushed to Maven Central Repository by Galex. Now we can use Gradle! [build.gradle](https://gist.github.com/galex/8281f5dee23e2c90caf2)

Answer (score 3):

You can access the underlying SQLite database through the DatabaseHelper class, which is available from the generated DAO:

```
ContactDao dao = new ContactDao(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = dao.getDbHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
// SELECT DISTINCT Locale FROM PALABRA
Cursor c = db.query(...);
```

You can also call getWriteableDatabase() on the DatabaseHelper class and it's safe to do so as storm-gen uses a singleton instance of the underlying SQLiteDatabase.

Comment: I'm looking for benchmark results for **storm-gen** via [android-orm-benchmark](https://github.com/littleinc/android-orm-benchmark)

Answer (score 1):

With reference to **David's** answer you may get trouble in setting up storm-gen lib in Android studio project for getting gradle files working so that the annotation generation works for the storm-gen.

if you want to run the helloworld program using android studio with storm-gen please do think of this [**solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499133/how-do-i-use-sqlite-db-storm-gen-with-android-studio-with-annotation-generation/22499135#22499135)

**code:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

import com.example.stormtestlib.Person;
import com.example.stormtestlib.TestingDB;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        TestingDB tt = TestingDB.getInstance(this);
        Person p = tt.getPerson(this);
        p.setMyString("blah blah");
        tt.savePerson(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
* A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
*/
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

source: [github](https://github.com/maiatoday/StormTest/blob/master/StormHelloWorldProject/StormHelloWorld/src/main/java/com/example/stormhelloworld/MainActivity.java)
Credit: Maia

**Update:**

storm-gen was just pushed to [Maven Central Repository so you can import and use it easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499133/how-do-i-use-sqlite-db-storm-gen-with-android-studio-with-annotation-generation/22499135#22499135).No we can use it with Gradle **[build.gradle](https://gist.github.com/galex/8281f5dee23e2c90caf2)**

```
// Top-level build.gradle 

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

// app module build.gradle

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.turbomanage.storm.sample"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    apt 'com.turbomanage.storm:storm-impl:0.98'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.turbomanage.storm:storm-api:0.98'
}
```

Credit: Galex