# How do I use SQLite DB storm-gen with android studio with annotation generation?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, storm-gen

I'm migrating from eclipse to Android studio,I have trouble in moving my eclipse project to Android studio.

**Details:**

[Storm-gen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495590/how-do-i-access-the-underlying-sqlite-database-when-using-storm-gen-for-android) is simple ORM for Android SQLite, I'm thinking of how can use that ORM framework in my android studio with gradle files working so that the annotation generation works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

storm-gen was just pushed to [Maven Central Repository so you can import and use it easily](http://ubiquoid.com/storm-gen-in-maven-central-repository/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best Solution with Storm-gen gradle build for Android Studio!

With reference to Maia's solution in [githhub/stormTest](https://github.com/maiatoday/StormTest):

> The idea was to figure out how to get the gradle files working so that
>   the annotation generation works with storm-gen Lightweight DAO lib in
>   Android studio.
>
> **There are three android studio projects:**
>
> - StormTestProject - simple app which access storm-genStorm
> - TestLibProject  - android library which has storm-gen inside
> - StormHelloWorldProject  - simple app that uses StormTestLibProject    generated aar
>
> **StormTestLibProject** will deploy the library to a local maven repo on your machine. You need to install maven
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install maven2
> ```
>
> In the **StormTestLibProject** you type ./gradlew install and it will
>   build the library, make the aar and put it in your local maven repo.
>
> In **StormHelloWorldProject** this library is simply access with a
>   dependancy in the build.gradle.
>
> *These projects were tested with gradle 1.8 and android studio 0.3.1 on ubuntu 13.10 64bit using maven 2.2.1.*
>
> Note:The generated sources are found in build/source/apt-generated.
>   You need to have the storm-api and storm-apt jars in the libs folders.